# Leaflet and the MapBox API - curved lines that follow the Earth's form

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox, mercator

Has anyone successfully implemented, or found a plugin that allows the MapBox API to draw the shortest possible line between two points on a map while taking Earth's curves into account? Google Maps already has this, see this link:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geometry-headings?hl=nl

Try to drag the markers around. I have no idea what the official term is for calculating routes this way on a mercator map, I will edit the title of this question as soon as I do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The term is called geodesic polylines or, in a case where the plane formed by the line intersects the center of the sphere, a great circle.

https://github.com/springmeyer/arc.js

Comment: Better late then never to accept this answer I suppose. Sorry it took so long.